# For Next Loop with Function Error

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I am trying to create a loop to update some "TextBox" already created on Userform.
The problem is that when I link the line

```
              For y = 2 * (3 + k) To 2 * (3 + k)
```

With

```
    For k = 0 To 7
```

I get a Mismatch Error. But if I define y = 6, everything goes fine.

Could you help me out?

Please, see below the entire code:

```
    Sub Update_TextBox_Preco()

    Dim k As Double
    Dim myarray2 As Variant
    Dim y As Double
    Dim Textbox As String
    Dim Textbox_1 As String
    Dim line As Variant

    Array with contained TextBox names
        myarray2 = Array("TextBox_Moeda_Atual", "TextBox_Medida_Atual", "TextBox_Acond_Atual", "TextBox_Lote_Atual", _
                    "TextBox_Incoterm_Atual", "TextBox_p_liq_atual", "TextBox_encargo_atual", "TextBox_Frete_Atual")

    For k = 0 To 7
    Textbox = myarray2(k)
              For y = 2 * (3 + k) To 2 * (3 + k)
                 UserForm1.Controls(Textbox).Value = Worksheets("PANEL").Cells(y, 45).Value
              Next y
    Next k

    End Sub
```

Comment: I just tried and didn't get an error, where is the error happening?  Your 2nd loop just produces 6,8,10,12,14,16,18 and 20, so why not have a variable y, starting at 6 incrementing by 2 each time?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav the loop/sequence that is giving error is the  `For y = 2 * (3 + k) To 2 * (3 + k)` which is linked on For `k = 0 To 7`. But if I set `For y = 6 to 6`, for example, it goes normally.

Comment: You should probably `Dim` `k` and `y` as `Long` instead of `Double`. There may be some rounding errors happening?

Comment: @bobajob I've already tried to `Dim k`and `Dim y as Long`, but got the same "Run-time Mismatch Error".

Comment: See my answer... just get rid of the y loop since it only triggers once.

Comment: What line throws the error? I suspect `UserForm1.Controls(Textbox).Value = Worksheets("PANEL").Cells(y, 45).Value`. So have a look what `Worksheets("PANEL").Cells(y, 45).Value` is if the error occurs.

Comment: Regardless of whether that's where the error stems from, a `For` loop counter should never be a floating-point type, @bobajob has a point. Make them `Long` integers and get *that* off the plate already.

Comment: FWIW `Textbox As String` is shadowing the `TextBox` type, which may or may not be problematic. Avoid naming locals with identifiers that already exist in reference type libraries.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks a lot! I just put `0.0` in the IFERROR function instead of only `0` and everything went well!

Comment: @Mat'sMug  and bobajob  also many thanks for your support!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get rid of the `y` loop.  It only triggers once so just set `y` each time you move through the `k` loop.

```
Sub Update_TextBox_Preco()

Dim k As Long
Dim myarray2 As Variant
Dim y As Long
Dim TextBoxUp As String
Dim Textbox_1 As String
Dim line As Variant

'Array with contained TextBox names
    myarray2 = Array("TextBox_Moeda_Atual", "TextBox_Medida_Atual", "TextBox_Acond_Atual", "TextBox_Lote_Atual", _
                "TextBox_Incoterm_Atual", "TextBox_p_liq_atual", "TextBox_encargo_atual", "TextBox_Frete_Atual")

For k = 0 To 7
    TextBoxUp = myarray2(k)
    y = 2 * (3 + k)
    UserForm1.Controls(TextBoxUp).Value = Worksheets("PANEL").Cells(y, 45).Value
Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: the error still persists, but if I omit the `k` from  `y = 2 * (3 + k)` as `y = 2 * 3`, it goes well.

Comment: @Petter_Mendes I copied and pasted this code exactly and didn't get an error until `UserForm1.Controls` line (because I obviously don't have your text boxes built).  I had NO error on Type Mismatch.

Comment: Updated per @Mat'sMug Suggestion

Comment: Many Thanks for the help!